# How to check a specific condition while using JQUERY plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, plugins, var

I am implementing the following code:-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
url:"YOUR_FILE_UPLOAD_URL",
fileName:"myfile"
});
});
</script>
```

I want to know that what is url, filename, Are they variables , arrays or attributes?
Secondly how to apply if condition if i am wanting to check the url?
It would be like that if(!url)??
Please advise with best.

Comment: a ref to the used plugin would be usefull, looking at the docs, it says: `url:
Server URL which handles File uploads` and `fileName:
Name of the file input field. Default is file`

Comment: sir, cant we apply if condition in this script as i am trying to check my url ?

Comment: the url should always be the same, it must point to a serverside-script like php that actually handles the uploaded files and saves them on the system. the fileName property is just the key of the form-data so that you can explicitly access it in your server-script. just check the docs, theres a section about it http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php#doc

Comment: Thanks sir for sharing the docs link. stay blessed.

Comment: Sir, can you please let me know thata how to display error. There is showError option but how to display it that is confusing me.

Comment: It says that the default is "true" so you dont have to set it to display errors, check the browser console, check the `onError ` part, you can add a function to console.log() the errorMessages and stuff